# How to set a specific row in a modified list view

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have a problem to how can I display a different xml layout for a modified list view.

My list view acts as a comment section.

I just want to display a edit and delete button for the owner of that certain comment and display nothing at all if he/she is not the owner of it.

this is my sample code
btw I am using json

```
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.sessionGetIdAccountType();
        String session_user_id = user.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_ID);
        int integer_session_user_id = Integer.parseInt(session_user_id);
        String user_id = "";
        boolean usercomment = false;
        try {
            commentData = json.getJSONArray("list");
            for (int i = 0; i < commentData.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject source = commentData.getJSONObject(i);
                Commenters commenter = new Commenters();
                commenter.setName(source.getString("User_Fname") + " "
                        + source.getString("User_Lname"));
                commenter.setDate(source.getString("Comment_Date"));
                commenter.setUsername(source.getString("User_Username"));
                commenter.setComment(source.getString("Comment_Content"));
                int integer_user_id = Integer.parseInt(user_id = source
                        .getString("User_ID"));
                commenterList.add(commenter);
                ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.comment_list);
                if (integer_session_user_id == integer_user_id) {
                    usercomment = true;
                } else {
                    usercomment = false;
                }



                if (usercomment) {
                    adapter2 = new CommenterAdapter2(
                            getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_user,
                            commenterList);
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter2);
                } else {
                    adapter = new CommenterAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.layout.row, commenterList);
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
        }

         catch (Exception e) {
            e.fillInStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show to use how it looks now?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help you.

```
public class TestListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
static final int TYPE_CELL = 1;

public TestListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Object> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        default:
            return TYPE_CELL;
    }
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case TYPE_HEADER: {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.tools_list_item_card_big, parent, false);
            }
            break;
            case TYPE_CELL: {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.tools_list_item_card_small, parent, false);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

}

> in getview method of adapter switch case is used for inflating different views on listview row  & getItemViewType() returns which view i want to use you can also check this by adding property in array list custom model.